# ¿Texto flotante al pasar el cursor por sobre una imagen?

Tags: html, css

Necesito colocar un título que aparezca solo al pasar el cursor sobre la imagen, he probado con el atributo title pero no funciona.

```html
<img src="mad.png" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Comment: El ejemplo que pusiste no tiene atributo `title` y la imagen no está en una url pública. Podrías cambiar eso para que podamos probar.

Comment: Puedes ocupar la librería de JQueryUI
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: que el titulo aparezca dónde? veo respuestas apresuradas y eso no está claro

Comment: Asimismo, podrías indicarnos en que explorador no te funciona el atributo [`title`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp).

Comment: Era una etiqueta de ejemplo, lo solucione con las respuestas muchas gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dos maneras:

1) Añade la etiqueta title:

```
<div title="Texto flotante">Pon el cursor encima</div>
```

2) Utiliza JS y CSS para poner cualquier recuadro dentro, tal y como puedes encontrar en este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702867/html-tooltip-position-relative-to-mouse-pointer)

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, freesoul. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Para futuras respuestas, te recomiendo leer [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer un tooltip simplemente usando el pseudoselector `:after`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let figure = document.getElementById('photo');
  let directions = document.getElementById('directions');

  directions.addEventListener('change', function () {
    figure.setAttribute('tooltip-dir', this.value);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

img {
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

figure:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(title);
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 110%;
  top: 30px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

figure[tooltip-dir="left"]:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 110%;
}

figure[tooltip-dir="bottom"]:after,
figure[tooltip-dir="top"]:after {
  left: 50%;
    right: auto;

  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

figure[tooltip-dir="bottom"]:after {
  bottom: auto;
  top: 110%;
}

figure[tooltip-dir="top"]:after {
  bottom: 110%;
  top: auto;
}

figure:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<figure id="photo" title="¿Qué hay, bro?" tooltip-dir="left">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/c0/f0/9f/c0f09f6c4d59f94f60f27ba6a05b8f57.jpg"/>
</figure>

<select id="directions">
  <option value="left" selected>Left</option>
  <option value="right">Right</option>
  <option value="bottom">Bottom</option>
  <option value="top">Top</option>
</select>
```

Comment: como se puede hacer para que solo aparesca el tooltip sin el title

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería mediante `CSS`, te dejo un ejemplo muy simple pero funcional.

```css
/* Invisible texto */
figcaption {
  display:none; 
  transition: all .5s;
}
/* Visible texto */
figure:hover > figcaption {
  display:block;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://oi41.tinypic.com/30mmgbd.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" />
  <figcaption>Tu texto</figcaption>
</figure>
```